# Extending DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration causes Swagger PageNotFound

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I had Swagger (2.7.0) properly configured and working fine together with Spring Boot (1.5.4) but after I added custom class extending `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` (used to configure own `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`) Swagger stopped being displayed with the below WARN message:

```
 o.s.w.s.PageNotFound | No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [<swagger_page.html>] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

I'm wodering why.

Comment: When extending `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` you are disabling the Spring Boot auto configuration for the web classes possibly breaking things.

Comment: Are you sure? - Everything else works fine, hm.

Comment: Yes I'm sure... Wy did you need to extend it? Generally when doing things like this you are doing things you shouldn't be doing (or using the framework in away you shouldn't be using it).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a smart way to have both: Spring Boot auto config and `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` extended?

Comment: Long story short: I had to register custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` -
 the one that deals with annotations (e.g @RequestParameter) not the regular custom ones which will be be triggerd for such arguments.

Comment: What is it that that needs to do? If you want to further configure the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` just register a `BeanPostProcessor` which does just that.

Comment: Generally `BeanPostProcessor` approach would work but not for this case. I need to change `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.argumentResolvers` list and class api does not support that.

Comment: You should register a custom resolver which you can quite easily add.

Comment: Custom resolver will not work with annotations, moreover I want that resolver to be triggered first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and added this to the `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration`

```
@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

as described on http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api config without `springmvc` which in this case seems like it's being overridden.

Alternatively you could extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and just change what you need that way the default configs for other things remain untouched